# Show that there is no epimorphism from ($\mathbb{Q}$, +) to ($\mathbb{Z}$, +)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I can't figure out why such an epimorphism cannot exist.

I think the fact that a bijection exists between the $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ throws me off a little. What is it about having a *homomorphic* surjection that causes problems?

Comment: Suppose you had a homomorphism with $h(x_1) = 1$. Then derive a contradiction.

Comment: add up for Daniel's hint... (Hoping that this would not spoil the fun)... $f(x_1)=2f(\frac{x_1}{2})$..

Comment: Thanks for the hints Daniel Fischer and Praphulla Koushik. I posted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel Fischer and Praphulla Koushik for providing the hints.

Suppose there exists an epimorphism $f:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, there's  $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(x)=1$.

$$1=f(x)=f\left(2\cdot\frac{x}{2}\right)=2f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}=f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$

Which is a contradiction, since $f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

Daniel's hint should suffice, but here's another approach:

1) Show $\;\Bbb Q\;$ is *divisible*, meaning: for any natural $\;n\;$ and any $\;g\in \Bbb Q\;$ there exists $\;x\in \Bbb Q\;$ s.t. $\;nx=g\;$ ;

2) If $\;G\;$ is divisible and $\;\phi:G\to H\;$ is a group homomorphism, then $\;\phi(G)\;$ is also divisible

3) $\;\Bbb Z\;$ is not divisible

Extra stuff not related to question: the only finite group that is divisible is the trivial one.