# Prove there does not exist any epimorphism of $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ onto $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Prove there does not exist any epimorphism of $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ onto $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$. How do I proceed on this?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/963870/show-that-there-is-no-epimorphism-from-mathbbq-to-mathbbz?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

1) $\;\Bbb Q\;$ is a *divisible* group, i.e.:

$$\forall\, n\in\Bbb N\,,\,\,q\in\Bbb Q\;\;\exists\,r\in\Bbb Q\;\;s.t.\;\;q=nr$$

2) Every homomorphic image of a divisible group is divisible

3) $\;\Bbb Z\;$ is **not** divisible.

Comment: [Nice job](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/963915/10014)

Comment: I don't see a reason to downvote someone now and then posting a similar answer to a duplicate question nearly six months apart. I disagree with the downvote here.

Comment: Not only that: seeing the link Najib put, *I myself* answered that question...like I remember. Oh, well.

Comment: I think the downvotes are probably more for answering questions that are missing context (i.e. doing people's homework for them) rather than because of theduplicate.

Comment: Even assuming that @DerekHolt The OP still needs to complete quite a bit here: why are the rationals divisible and why the integers aren't, why a homomorphic image of a divisible grous is also divisible, etc. I'd hardly call the above "an answer" but rather some hints towards an answer.

Comment: Yes that's true! But you could solve the problem directly, without mentioning divisbility: if $\phi:{\mathbb Q} \to {\mathbb Z}$ is an epimorphism, then there exists $a$ with $\phi(a)=1$, and so $2\phi(a/2) = 1$, contradiction, because $2x=1$ has bo solution in ${\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Of course you could: did anyone claim otherwise? What has that to do with the downvotes?

Comment: Nothing at all! I had moved on to discussing the mathematics. In any case, I wasn't agreeing with the downvotes particularly, I was just trying to explain them (probably a bad idea).